# how to display an alert if a condition is verified using sweetalert

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert2

I'm working with an angular application, and I want to show an alert using sweetalert if a condition is verified, so how to do that without using a click button

I tried to do this but didn't work

```
<div *ngIf="Users.length == 0" [swal]="showSwal">
      <swal #showSwal 
        title=" No Data  " 
        text="No data To Show" 
        showCloseButton="true" 
        type="warning">
      </swal>
</div>
```

Normally sweetalert call the swal in a button like this 
Simple example:

```
<swal
  #deleteSwal
  title="Delete {{ file.name }}?"
  text="This cannot be undone"
  type="question"
  [showCancelButton]="true"
  [focusCancel]="true"
  (confirm)="deleteFile(file)">
</swal>

<!-- With [swal]: -->
<button [swal]="deleteSwal">Delete {{ file.name }}</button>
```

In my case i want call the alert in a div.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the variable name "Users", it might be an observable or @Input(). So if it's an observable, write showSwal.fire() in it's subscribe method. If it's an @Input(), then you can write it on ngOnChanges() lifecycle hook.

Comment: Thanks ,the condition is right, but the problem is: how to call this alert in a div or How can I do an auto click if it is obligatory to use a button?

Comment: that's what i wrote. U don't call it in a div, u call it in your .js or .ts file